# Off By One Error within a loop?

Tags: c++

So I have an off-by-one error in my while loop within my client code - for some reason the code executes 11 times when it should execute 10 (even though it doesn't actually print out the 11th item).  I'm not sure where the error lies (I've even printed out the condition test and it increments properly, it just asks for another player when it shouldn't)

client.cpp

```
//Client File
#include "sortedNFL.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main() {

  //Declare necessary variables
  NFL teamPlayer; //holds created player
  SortedNFL NFLroster; //create roster list
  bool inputCheck; //flag to check if user wants to add more players
  char inputFlag; //input to check if user wants to add more players
  char printFlag; //character input for user to print
  bool printCheck; //flag to check if user wants to print

  //set necessary variables
  inputCheck = true; //set input check to true


  //begin user input
  while(inputCheck == true) {
    cout << "Enter your player's first name: ";
    cin >> teamPlayer.firstName;
    cout << "Enter your player's last name: ";
    cin >> teamPlayer.lastName;
    cout << "Enter your player's position: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin,teamPlayer.position);
    cout << "Enter your player's school: ";
    getline(cin,teamPlayer.school);

    if(!NFLroster.IsFull()) { //check if total size is less than 10 (maximum amount of players)
      NFLroster.PutItem(teamPlayer); //add player to list
      cout << "Would you like to enter another player? (Y/N): "; //check if user wants to add another player
      cin >> inputFlag;
      if(inputFlag == 'N' || inputFlag == 'n') { //if user is done adding players
        inputCheck = false; //set check to false (break while loop)
        cout << "Would you like to print out the current roster? (Y/N): "; //check if user wants to print roster
        cin >> printFlag;
        if(printFlag == 'Y' || printFlag == 'y') //if user wants to print roster, set check to true
          printCheck = true;
        else if (printFlag == 'N' || printFlag == 'n') { //if user doesn't want to print roster, set check to false
          printCheck = false;
        }
      }
    }
    else if(NFLroster.IsFull()) { //when total players equals 10, print out alert
      inputCheck = false;
      cout << "The roster is full! We will print it out below."
           << endl
           << endl;
    }
  }
  if(NFLroster.IsFull()) //when total size equals ten, print out roster
    NFLroster.PrintList(); //call print function
  else if(printCheck) { //if print check is true, then print list early
    NFLroster.PrintList(); //print out list
  }
}
```

sortedNFL.cpp

```
#include "sortedNFL.h"
#include <iostream>

struct NodeType
{
  NFL player;
  NodeType* next;
};

SortedNFL::SortedNFL()  // Class constructor
{
  length = 0;
  nflList = NULL;
}

bool SortedNFL::IsFull() const
{
  if (length == 10)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

int SortedNFL::GetLength() const
{
  return length;
}

void SortedNFL::MakeEmpty()
{
  NodeType* tempPtr;

  while (nflList != NULL)
  {
    tempPtr = nflList;
    nflList = nflList->next;
    delete tempPtr;
  }
  length = 0;
}

NFL SortedNFL::GetItem(NFL& playerRequested, bool& found)
{
  bool moreToSearch; //flag for more items to search
  NodeType* location; 

  location = nflList; //initial location is first item in NFL list
  found = false; //flag for if item is found
  moreToSearch = (location != NULL);

  int compare_result = playerRequested.lastName.compare(location->player.lastName);
  while (moreToSearch && !found) //while there is more to search and item is not found
  {
    if (compare_result > 0)
    {
      location = location->next;
      moreToSearch = (location != NULL);
    }
    else if (compare_result == 0 && playerRequested.firstName.compare(location->player.firstName) == 0)
    {
      found = true; 
      playerRequested = location->player;
    }
    else if (compare_result < 0)
    {
      moreToSearch = false;
    }
  }
  return playerRequested;
}

void SortedNFL::PutItem(NFL inputPlayer)
{
  NodeType* newNode;    // pointer to node being inserted
  NodeType* predLoc;    // trailing pointer
  NodeType* location;   // traveling pointer
  bool moreToSearch;

  location = nflList;
  predLoc = NULL;
  moreToSearch = (location != NULL);

  // Find insertion point.
  while (moreToSearch) //while moreToSearch is true
  {
    int compare_result = inputPlayer.lastName.compare(location->player.lastName);
    if (compare_result > 0)
    {
      predLoc = location;
      location = location->next;
      moreToSearch = (location != NULL);
    }
    else if (compare_result < 0)
    {
      moreToSearch = false;
    }
    else if (compare_result == 0) {
      int compare_result_firstname = inputPlayer.firstName.compare(location->player.firstName);
      if (compare_result_firstname > 0) 
      {
        predLoc = location;
        location = location->next;
        moreToSearch = (location != NULL);
      }
      else if(compare_result_firstname < 0) {
        moreToSearch = false;   
      }
    }
  }
  // Prepare node for insertion
  newNode = new NodeType;
  newNode->player = inputPlayer;
  // Insert node into list.
  if (predLoc == NULL)         // Insert as first
  {
    newNode->next = nflList;
    nflList = newNode;
  }
  else
  {
    newNode->next = location;
    predLoc->next = newNode;
  }
  length++;
  std::cout << length;
}
void SortedNFL::DeleteItem(NFL playerDeleted)
{
  NodeType* location = nflList;
  NodeType* tempLocation;

  // Locate node to be deleted.
  int compare_result_lastname = playerDeleted.lastName.compare(location->player.lastName);
  int compare_result_firstname = playerDeleted.firstName.compare(location->player.firstName);
  if (compare_result_lastname == 0 && compare_result_firstname == 0)
  {
    tempLocation = location;
    nflList = nflList->next;    // Delete first node.
  }
  else
  {
    while (compare_result_lastname != 0)
      location = location->next;

    // Delete node at location->next
    tempLocation = location->next;
    location->next = (location->next)->next;
  }
  delete tempLocation;
  length--;
}

void SortedNFL::ResetList()
{
  currentPos = NULL;
} 

NFL SortedNFL::GetNextItem()
{
  NFL playerRequested;
  if (currentPos == NULL)
    currentPos = nflList;
  playerRequested = currentPos->player; 
  currentPos = currentPos->next;
  return playerRequested;

}
void SortedNFL::PrintList() {
      NFL tempPlayer; //holds player item
      ResetList(); //reset list to begin printing
      for (int i = 1; i <= length; ++i)
      {
        tempPlayer = GetNextItem();
        std::cout << "Player " << i
             << endl;
        std::cout << "First Name: " << tempPlayer.firstName
             << endl;
        std::cout << "Last Name: " << tempPlayer.lastName
             << endl;
        std::cout << "Position: " << tempPlayer.position
             << endl;
        std::cout << "School: " << tempPlayer.school
             << endl;
      }
}
SortedNFL::~SortedNFL() //class destructor
{
  NodeType* tempPtr;

  while (nflList != NULL)
  {
    tempPtr = nflList;
    nflList = nflList->next;
    delete tempPtr;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your loop is programmed to do that. Walk through in your head what happens when you enter the last player.

Comment: tip: instead of `inputCheck == true`, give the variable a proper *self-descriptive name* and use just that name as expression. as a rule never compare a boolean against `true`, because it's a habit that can cause problems for other boolean types than the built-in `bool`, and even for that.

Comment: @Radiodef heh, I was focused entirely on the actual function itself that I didn't notice how I had set it up within the loop. Thanks for that.

Comment: It's extremely helpful to learn how to use the debugger early, so you can step through the code and figure out these sorts of things by yourself. Doing so can be extremely educational.